# How to check if a value is already present in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

I created a code that allows me to send values from form1 to form2, I need to know, however, before sending the values, if these are already present. I would avoid the redundancy of information in form2.
I access DataGridView through this object:

```
mChildForm.DataGrid1
```

Who can help me build this mode through an example?

Comment: form1 could send the data to form2 who only adds it if/when it meets the conditions.  Since the DGV resides in Form2, leave it to manage the control as needed

Comment: I do this in form1? I need to read the entire contents of this form. Or go to encounter problems?

Comment: which form is the childform and do you start form2 from form1`? Is there a Datagridview on both forms or only on one? and if it is only on one which is it? your description lacks information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Query string** to pass throw the vales , for example if i have this form from table .. 
in page.aspx

```
<tr>
      <td style="border: 3px solid #ccc;">
                <strong>&nbsp;Check in&nbsp;</strong></td>
            <td style="border: 3px solid #ccc;">
                :&nbsp;
                <asp:literal id="ltdArrival" runat="server"></asp:literal>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 3px solid #ccc;">
                <strong>Rooms No</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; :&nbsp;
                <asp:literal id="ltdRoomNo" runat="server"></asp:literal>
            </td>
 </tr>
```

when i need to send it for an other page put in page.aspx.vb in your button or literal code ... etc

```
ltlChangeSearch.Text = "<a href='" & "MakeReservation.aspx?From=" & Request.QueryString("From") & "&RoomNo=" & Request.QueryString("RoomNo") & "'>" ltlChangeSearch.Text += "<span class='spanbtn' style='text-align:center; text-decoration:none;'>Change Search</span></a>"
```